# Teamcity after git force push

Tags: git, teamcity

I've had to revert to a previous commit in my master branch in git which has meant I've had to force push the changes up to Teamcity.

It's seems as though Teamcity has got into a bind and it thinks that any newly triggered builds are actually building an older version of the project (it's correct, I reverted from Build Number 750 to 747)

When running the build it displays this:

[image]

When I look in the history it looks like this (all builds after I reverted are grey)

[image]

Is there anything I can do to make Teamcity think I am building the latest? Maybe clearing logs or something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always delete the builds for the reverted commits that no longer exist. To do this go to the build details page then click "Actions" > "Remove".

Comment: This is the only way I could get it to accept the latest build.

Answer (score 1):

In a more recent version of TeamCity (9.1.3), we managed to get around this by triggering a custom build with the following parameters:

1. Changes tab: Include changes: Select the latest commit explicitly, instead of "latest changes..."
2. Dependencies tab: Tick the checkbox for "rebuild all snapshots transitively". This just makes all dependencies change from *auto* to *rebuild*. (This only applies if you have dependences, of course.)